# Failing to capture video using OpenCV and Python on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, opencv, webcam, video-capture

I'm trying to write a simple python script to capture an image from a webcam using OpenCV. This is running on Ubuntu 11.10 32-bit.

when I run lsusb in the terminal i get:

> > Bus 002 Device 002: ID 045e:00f7 Microsoft Corp. LifeCam VX-1000

Which leads me to believe that the driver for the camera is installed

In a python shell I type:
capture=cv.CaptureFromCAM(0) # also  tried -1, 1, 2, 3

but capture is always null.

I also tried:
capture = cv.CreateCameraCapture(0)

But i get the same results.

Would appreciate any help

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

Merely probing the driver does not validate that the camera will work.

Here is a [ubuntu support page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Webcam) on testing your camera with vlc

Basically you should try something like :

```
$ vlc v4l2:///dev/video0
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this camera is supported by OpenCV.

OpenCV has a [compatibility list](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Welcome/OS), check if yours is there.

Comment: Thank you for that. I'll try a different hardware and see if the problem persists. The list you pointed out is very useful